# How to specify a particular plot marker from Mathematica's automatic list of markers?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica has ten basic plot markers which are used cyclically when making a `ListPlot` with `PlotMarkers->Automatic`. There are filled and empty versions of circle, square, diamond, up triangle, and down triangle. The eleventh marker repeats filled circle, but in a different color. For example,

`ListPlot[Table[{i, i + #}, {i, 1, 7}] & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
    9, 10, 11}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`

gives

[image: PlotMarkers defaults]

Is it possible to specify a particular plot marker from this set of default markers? The `FullForm` of the above plot shows that Mathematic uses fonts for those symbols, i.e.

`Style["\[FilledCircle]", Rule[FontSize, 8.96`]]`

which one could set by hand, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in the way that one can pick from the default plot colors using  `ColorData[1][n]`, where `n` is the nth color.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
Graphics`PlotMarkers[]
```

has the information you want, although it's very undocumented and subject to change.

Comment: Still a bit awkward for specifying the size ({`Graphics``PlotMarkers[][[3,1]],7}`), but it works, thanks.

Comment: The output is a list of `{marker, size}` pairs, so you could just use `{Graphics\`PlotMarkers[][[3]]}`, if the default size is acceptable...

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer, but you don't get an up vote because you guys didn't document PlotMarkers sufficiently.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the GUI interface, also note that you can select these characters from the Typesetting Palette, and some even have keyboard shortcuts, e.g. `ESC fci ESC` or `ESC fsq ESC` for filled circles and squares, respectively. (Tested in Mathematica 9)

Answer (score 1):

The inbuilt symbol in Mathematica can be used to define a set of symbols and use them in the order one likes.

{filledcircle, filledsquare, filleddiamond, filleduptriangle,
filleddowntriangle, circle, square, diamond, uptriangle,
downtriangle} = Graphics`PlotMarkers[][[All, 1]]